# Copy-assigning an unordered map with incompatible allocators

Tags: c++, unordered-map, allocator

Consider the following dummy allocator (created for the sake of example):

```
template<typename T> class C
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;

    C() = default;

    template<typename U>
    C(C<U> const &a)
    {}


    T* allocate(std::size_t n, T const* = nullptr)
    {
        return new T[n];
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
    {
        return;
    }

    typedef value_type       *pointer;
    typedef const value_type *const_pointer;
    typedef value_type       &      reference;
    typedef value_type const &const_reference;
    typedef std::size_t       size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t    difference_type;
    static       pointer address(reference x) { return &x; }
    static const_pointer address(const_reference x) { return &x; }
    static size_type max_size() { return std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max(); }
    template <typename U> static void destroy(U* ptr) { ptr->~U(); }
    template <typename U> struct rebind { using other = C<U>; };

    template<typename U, typename... Args>
    static void construct(U* ptr, Args&&... args) {
        new (ptr) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<class T1, class T2>
bool operator==(C<T1> const& lhs, C<T2> const& rhs)
{
    return std::addressof(lhs) == std::addressof(rhs);
}

template<class T1, class T2>
bool operator!=(C<T1> const& lhs, C<T2> const& rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

Most of this code is boiler plate. The crucial detail is that any two instances of an allocator will be considered incompatible - `bool operator==` always returns `false`. When I try to use this allocator with most STL containers such as `std::vector` to copy-assign very simple elements, such as:

```
std::vector<int, C<int>> a;
a = std::vector<int, C<int>>();
```

Things work, and I get expected behavior. However, when I do the same thing, but with `std::unordered_map` instead, I get different behavior on the two platforms I need to support. On Linux with GCC 7.1, I continue to get expected behavior. On Windows with VS 2015, however, I get an assertion failure stating `containers incompatible for swap` in a VS header titled `xmemory0`. Note that the code used for `std::unordered_map` is pretty much the same as the above for `std::vector`:

```
using B = std::unordered_map<int, int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, C<std::pair<int const, int>>>;
B b;
b = B();
```

Is there something inherently wrong with my allocator, and GCC 7.1 is giving me undefined behavior? If not, is this a failure with the VS 2015 runtime library? If so, why is this failure only present with `unordered_map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have allocators that uniquely own state, they [must be](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) [CopyConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible). E.g. you should switch from `std::unique_ptr`s to `std::shared_ptr`s.

You should relax your comparisons

```
template<class T1, class T2>
bool operator==(C<T1> const& lhs, C<T2> const& rhs)
{
    return /* check equality of some member of C */;
}

template<class T1, class T2>
bool operator!=(C<T1> const& lhs, C<T2> const& rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

You can also probably benefit from adhering to the [Rule of zero/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), and defining `propogate_on_container_copy_assignment`, `propogate_on_container_move_assignment` and `propogate_on_container_swap` as `std::true_type`

A hint as to where MSVC is tripping up

> Note: swapping two containers with unequal allocators if `propagate_on_container_swap` is `false` is undefined behavior.

Comment: That works, thanks. Do you have any idea as to why MSVC only trips up on `unordered_map`s? What is special about those? (Note: This is purely for my own curiosity, you've answered the main question - thanks again.)

Comment: I can only guess. It might be because of having rebound the allocator to the node type

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the edit - the initial allocator that I actually have in my code base has a more complicated `operator==`, but I noticed that the problem only occurred when it was returning `false` (hence the explicit set to `false` to force the issue). When I replace my `operator==` (and `operator!=`) with your suggestion, I unfortunately still get the same behavior.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Copy-ctor or assignment of a conforming allocator *must* yield an equal one. See T.C.'s answer.

Comment: @L.F. yep, finally got there. I was always suspicious of the `==`

Comment: @Caleth Allocators *can* have state. It's only that copies must compare equal.

Comment: @Caleth But I reverted downvote regarding your attitude.

Comment: @L.F. no worries. Added some clarification

Comment: @Caleth Can you explain a little bit what "uniquely" here means? I have problem understanding it :P

Comment: @L.F. It's the sense that that there can only ever be *one* `std::unique_ptr<T>` pointing to a particular `T` at a time.

Comment: Well.. Hmm.. Ok then

Answer (score 3):

This is not a conforming allocator. All copies of an allocator, including rebound ones, *must* compare equal to each other.

---

Additionally, `unordered_map`'s `value_type` is `pair<const Key, Value>`, so your example should use `C<pair<const int, int>>`.

Comment: Would using, e.g., `return std::addressof(lhs) == std::addressof(rhs)` as suggested by user Caleth in his above answer remedy this? If so, I've done that and I still get the same behavior - I can edit that into the question to make it better. Regarding `int` vs `const int` - I've made that change as well (again, will modify question), but no difference in result.

Comment: No. As long as copies are unequal, undefined behavior is there.

Comment: @L.F.: Fair enough - can you point me to a quote from the standard? My knowledge of allocators is woefully limited (as I typically just use `std::allocator`) and I'm always happy to learn more.

Comment: @user74427 http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements#tab:utilities.allocator.requirements

Comment: Pay attention to this:
`X u(a); X u = a;`
Shall not exit via an exception. 
Ensures: `u == a`